# Can employees not use sick time if they call out sick without repercussions?

Tags: human-resources, work-experience, sickness

Here is the situation:

Employee called out sick and gave a doctor's note to HR. HR said the doctors note was good. Employee than requested manager that manager not input sick time for the days absent. HR than wants to label this as an unexcused absence because employee did not want to use sick time. Employee recieves counseling notice for unexcused absence. Employee is upset that he gets counseling notice although he has a doctor's note.

Does the employee have to use his sick time? and do companies ever offer something like an "excused absence"? Is HR right to give a counseling notice? Is the employee right for saving his sick time? ..Obviously the company can choose to give a counseling notice or not but what would be the pros and cons of giving or not giving an excused absence for this?

...any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you this "employee", and if not, what is your relationship to them?

Comment: Where I live, what you describe is not even possible. We don't have "sick time", the doctor decides if one is sick and there is unlimited time for that. Please state your country (maybe even state if in the US), so we can help you navigate this for your region.

Comment: "Employee than requested manager that manager not input sick time for the days absent." why? at the fundamental basic level, in the company eyes either the employee is selling their working hours to the company and therefore doing some work in exchange (then the company seels the outcome of this work at an higher price and realize a profit).  If employee is absent without excusee, it is basically getting free hours paid from the company in exchange of nothing. No company works that way.

Comment: At any rate, this seems very company-specific and will likely be closed. Also, it is not even clear what you are asking. We cannot tell you whether someone is "right" without knowing your company's rules (and your jurisdiction). Please editing to focus on a clear question and add missing details such as jurisdiction and company rules.

Comment: If you are absent, it's either vacation time, sick time, authorized paid leave of some other sort, authorized unpaid leave, or you're just plain not at work and may be punished as well as not being paid. Pick one and only one

Comment: If you work somewhere which limits sick days to a number, it seems unlikely that you can get around the limit by just asking "don't use my sick time"

Comment: So you have a note from your doctor to excuse you absence but you don't want to use your excused absence and so HR rightly marks this as an unexcused absence, and you're upset by that. None of this makes logical sense.

Answer (score 3):

The employee is trying to have their cake and eat it here, having the absence be "excused" through the sick note but not have this use their sick time.. and it just doesn't work like that.

> Does the employee have to use his sick time?

I suppose they don't *have* to, unless of course they want to use sickness as the reason for the absence.

> and do companies ever offer something like an "excused absence"?

Yes! In fact "calling in sick" is an example of that very thing. Companies may offer other forms of "excused absence", but there usually is a reason attached to them, even if it's something as intentionally vague as a "duvet day".  If there's no policy around this, or even an ad-hoc agreement between the manager and the employee then you're heading to unexcused absence territory.

> Is HR right to give a counseling notice?

From the sounds of it, yes. If the employee wishes to (effectively) recant their sick note as being the reason for the absence, seemingly without providing a replacement reason, then it's an unexcused absence. What else could it be? That said, given they literally have a doctor's note HR should just be applying the normal process and recording the absence as sick, whether the employee is happy with that or not is immaterial.

> Is the employee right for saving his sick time?

I'd say no - they were sick, this caused them to miss work. That's literally what sick time is for. If they've got some health concerns that they are worried will mean they are going to be needing the sick time in the near future that's a separate conversation for how that should be handled with respect to the policy.

> ..Obviously the company can choose to give a counseling notice or not but what would be the pros and cons of giving or not giving an excused absence for this?

"Pros" to giving an excused absence (as opposed to using the sick time) for this are that it might being the whole palaver to a close soonest. Honestly that's about all I could come up with, and even that's tissue-thin. As for the "Cons", where to start? You're showing the employee (and any other employees that know what happened) that the rules don't apply to them. So you'd have to expect that they (and possibly others) will do this exploit again in the future.

If the company wants to give unlimited, or even just really, really generous sick time there's nothing *wrong* with that at all (personally I *hate* miserly sick time policies - at some point you're just punishing people for things out of their control) but in that case that should be the policy. Having a policy and having staff just decide to opt-out of the bits they don't like is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

The answer highly depends on your company policy, and even the labor law in your country regarding "**sick time**".

---

In general, suppose your company policy has a "sick time" policy that requires that an employee, who is sick, must use the "sick time". Then, if you call out "sick" and have a doctor's note saying that you are "sick", you should have used your "sick time" per the company policy.

That "sick time" may be fully paid 100% by your company and/or your insurance company, or partially paid by the company and/or the insurance company, or unpaid 100%.

---

I am not sure why you request your manager not to count your absent days as "sick time".

In general, in many companies in the US, an employee, who is sick, should use their general PTO (Paid Time Off) until they run out their PTO.

---

**Furthermore, this is an example of a short-term and long-term disability insurance plan:**

In Texas, USA, there are insurances that offer both short-term and long-term disability coverage as follows:

> The Texas Income Protection PlanSM (TIPP) offers short-term and
> long-term disability coverage that protects your income by paying a
> percentage of your paycheck if you become disabled and can't work due
> to a medical illness, injury, or pregnancy. Both plans are available
> to active employee.

Here is the [LINK](https://www.ers.texas.gov/active-employees/optional-add-on-benefits/texas-income-protection-plan-tipp#:%7E:text=The%20Texas%20Income%20Protection%20Plan,illness%2C%20injury%2C%20or%20pregnancy.):